# Ubuntu won't detect digital camera

Tags: usb, camera

When I plug in my digital camera that has a memory stick in it, the camera is then set to PC mode and nothing happens.

Is there a way I can mount it?

Running lsusb it comes up as:
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0489:d008 Foxconn / Hon Hai

Answer (score 1):

Set the camera to auto and install `gphoto2` and `gphotofs` via software center or terminal.

The camera mode needs to be set to auto and it will select the best mode dependent on the connection. Then install `gphoto2` and `gphotofs` from software center and your camera should work.

or using terminal `sudo apt-get install gphoto2 gphotofs`.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and add explanations on how to set the camera mode and now to install those packages. This may be clear for you, but new users with the same problem who find that answer can probably not understand it. Thank you!

Comment: There is no such mode, this camera has PC, or PC Camera when plugged into USB, both do nothing.

Comment: No luck for me; lsusb does not return any reference to the camera

Answer (score 0):

Have same error, fixed with

- Create folder **Camera** in **/home/username/**
  make this command
  `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/username/Camera`

Replace **username** with your folder name in home directory **/home/..../**

to find your device use `lsblk`